# Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried: (Webpack)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm creating this small project which uses the npm package `natural` when I bundle the code using webpack I get these warnings.

```
yarn run v0.18.1
$ webpack
Hash: ed778fcd450d09a90da4
Version: webpack 3.0.0
Time: 1250ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
bundle.js  731 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
  [40] ./node_modules/bindings 160 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
  [60] ./src/index.js 1.21 kB {0} [built]
    + 146 hidden modules

WARNING in ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js
76:22-40 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js
76:43-53 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
✨  Done in 1.93s.
```

and when I run the bundled code I get the following error.

```
/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:7860
    if (e.code !== 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') throw e;
                                       ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/build/WebWorkerThreads.node
 → /Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/build/Debug/WebWorkerThreads.node
 → /Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/build/Release/WebWorkerThreads.node
 → /Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/out/Debug/WebWorkerThreads.node
 → /Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/Debug/WebWorkerThreads.node
 → /Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/out/Release/WebWorkerThreads.node
 → /Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/Release/WebWorkerThreads.node
 → /Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/build/default/WebWorkerThreads.node
 → /Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/compiled/7.2.1/darwin/x64/WebWorkerThreads.node
    at bindings (/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:5488:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:17414:47)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.webpackEmptyContext.keys (/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:7857:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:17360:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:12097:27)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jakelacey/proj/ai/blankitv.0.0.1/dist/bundle.js:12000:66)
```

The code for the application is

```
var natural = require('natural');
var classifier = new natural.BayesClassifier();

// train.. 
classifier.addDocument('What is qqqq', ['question', 'unidentified']);
classifier.addDocument('can you give me an example of qqqq', ['example', 'maths', 'multiplicatication']);
classifier.addDocument('what is multiplication?', ['question', 'maths', 'multiplicatication']);
classifier.addDocument('addition', ['maths', 'addition']);
classifier.addDocument('division', ['maths', 'division']);

classifier.train();

console.log(classifier.classify('what is multiplication'));
console.log(classifier.classify('what is english'));
console.log(classifier.classify('what is english'));
console.log(classifier.classify('can you give me an example of multiplication'));
```

and the webpack configuration goes like so,

```
var path = require('path');
var FlowTypePlugin = require('flowtype-loader/plugin');

module.exports = {

  target: 'node',

  entry: './src/index.js',

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'flowtype-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',  
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new FlowTypePlugin()
  ]

}
```

Does anybody have a rough idea what is happening here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an error when running npm install (particularly when installing the native components of the package `node-webworker-threads`, which I think you are using) ? Do you have a native build tool chain (that includes a C compiler) installed for your development platform ?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I don't myself install `node-webworker-threads` it's a dependency that `natural` depends on... more specifically it is a `optionalDependency` I've never seen that before so I'm going to have to do some research

Comment: Ohh and it doesn't seem to be called `node-webworker-threads` it seems to be called `webworker-threads`.

Comment: @JakeLacey how did you resolve this issue? I installed webworker-threads as a dep but I'm still getting the error?

Comment: yes, i'm getting the same error and it's down to natural. I think this worked with node < 10.0, maybe downgrading could help...

Comment: not really an answer, but there's a bunch of extra info here:
https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural/issues/368